# Moving imageview from top to bottom in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I Have an ImageView in Center of my Screen, which i want to move up. where it remains at the Top.
I saw Tween Animation Documents and Tried it But Its Not Working.
Can any one Plz help me out solving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you tried view animation?

```
Animation an = new TranslateAnimation(fromX,fromY,toX,toY);//0,0 is the current       coordinates
an.setFillAfter(true);// to keep the state after animation is finished
yourView.startAnimation(an);// to start animation obviously
```

to make it move from bottom to top, get screen height and  use it to set "toY" parameter.

after few tries you will sure do it.

Comment: Actually my ImageView is in the Center and i want it to  move to the top and stop it there itself.

Comment: then just  set fromY=0 and  and set toY=screenHight

Comment: After moving from Center to Top the ImageView again Comes to teh Original Position(CENTER) and then New Activity is Called. I Want that ImageView to stay at the Top Only. pls Help